# Scheme: Loop Function in Racket

Tags: function, loops, scheme, racket

Write a recursive function that, given a positive integer `k`, computes the product `(1-1/2)(1-1/3)...(1-1/k)`.

I have tried to make a loop, but don't know where to start.
Any ideas?

Comment: Scheme use recursion to loop. Have got learned how to define a function?

Comment: Yes, just not exactly sure how to write this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! This example fits the pattern of [section 9.3 (Natural Numbers)](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_two.html#%28part._sec~3anats%29) from How To Design Programs, v2e. You should find a *lot* of helpful guidance there.